# Inverse cube law for gravitational field rather than square?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, vectors

I have a question about an example from a mathematics text book involving gravitational fields. Suppose we model galaxies as a countable number of points $\Pi\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with masses $\{m_X\}_{X\in\Pi}.$ Then the example claims that the gravitational field in the origin is given by a vector $\vec{g}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, which is given by
$$\vec{g} = -\sum_{X\in\Pi}\frac{Gm_X \vec{X}}{(X_1^2 + X_2^2 + X_3^2)^{3/2}},$$
where $G$ is the gravitational constant. My problem is with the denominator, which is $||X||^3,$ the cube of the distance of the galaxy from the origin, while I expected an inverse square law $||X||^2.$ Why should there be cubed distance here, rather than squared?

Comment: There is an $X$ in the numerator, so the total dependence is an inverse square law. Also you have a typo in the title.

Comment: @st.vit Of course, I see now. Thank you so much!